# How to let user send feedback through their default Email app

Tags: email, flutter

I would like to let my users send feedback through their default email app. 
For example, the user presses the "Send Feedback" button, and it opens their default email app with the recipient email id already entered. In this case, the recipient is our feedback email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_email_sender

Allows send emails from flutter using native platform functionality.

In android it opens default mail app via intent. compileSdkVersion 28 is used in this plugin and it should be used in app too.

In iOS MFMailComposeViewController is used to compose an email.

Example

```
final Email email = Email(
  body: 'Email body',
  subject: 'Email subject',
  recipients: ['example@example.com'],
  cc: ['cc@example.com'],
  bcc: ['bcc@example.com'],
  attachmentPath: '/path/to/attachment.zip',
);

await FlutterEmailSender.send(email);
```